# Writing vectors with hotkeys

Tags: vector, keyboard

I was searching the web for an answer but couldnt' find it:

I use Mathematica and instead of writing a vector like:

```
u = {1,2,3}
```

I was trying to do it hotkeys I found at the "Basic Math Assistant" like this:

*( -> Ctr-Enter -> Ctr-Enter -> 3 -> up -> 2 -> up -> 1 -> Ctr-Space -> )*

But if executed I get

```
{{1}, {2}, {3}}.
```

it looks like it is treated as a matrix and not a vector. This is a problem since I can't use such written vectors for calulations, with "cross" or similar.
Is there something I am missing, or doing wrong?
Why is it not the same as {1,2,3}

This is rather a cosmetic way of writing vectors, but I'm wondering if it would work.

Thanks.

Regards

Comment: Try using `Ctrl-,`. Using enter adds a row to the matrix, using , adds a column.

Comment: Using `Ctrl-,` will come out as `{{1,2,3}}`. I think trying to get this strange formatting is going to end up being more trouble than it's worth. If you need something pretty you can always output using `TableForm` or `MatrixForm` when you're done with your calculations.

Comment: Not an elegant solution, but if you really want to enter these vectors using `Ctrl-Enter` or `Ctrl-,`, you can always `Flatten` the result to get a 1-dimensional list.

Comment: Thanks,

I guess I just stick to the standard.
Thanks anyways

Comment: What does this question have to do with "Symbolic" vectors?

Comment: The linked thread might be enlightening reading.